# How to cover a page with regular polygon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I like to have a set of regular polygons in the background of a (DIN A0) page.
The pattern needs to be adjustable in regard of the thicknes of the lines of the polygons, and their color. Furthermore they should be arranged in a way that they are shifted so they create a nice pattern (picture just to show the pattern):
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

% Text or other content goes here
Here is your text or other content that should appear before the hexagons.

% Here come the hexagons
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, scale=0.1] % Scaling
  % Define the size of the hexagon
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{15} % Radius
  % Calculate the horizontal and vertical spacing between hexagons
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\horizontalSpacing}{3 * \radius * 0.866} % Smaller spacing
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\verticalSpacing}{3 * \radius} % Smaller spacing

  % Loop through rows and columns to draw hexagons
  \foreach \row in {0,...,7} {
    \foreach \col in {0,...,14} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\col*\horizontalSpacing}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{-\row*\verticalSpacing}
      \draw[fill=none,draw=black!20] (\x,\y) +(30:\radius cm) \foreach \angle in {90,150,...,360} {
        -- +(\angle:\radius cm)
      } -- cycle;
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The not so great result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little bit of math, you could come up with the following which should work with any paper size. The center of the lowermost hexagon sits at the lower left corner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
% Here come the hexagons
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
    % calculate the number of necessary rows and columns
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nx}{ceil(\paperwidth/2cm)+1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ny}{ceil(\paperheight/((1+sin(30))*1cm))+1}
    % anchor the whole picture at the lower left corner
    \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south west)}]
        \foreach \row in {0,...,\ny} {
            \foreach \col in {0,...,\nx} {
                \draw[black!20] 
                    % directly calculate the center of the hexagon
                    ({cos(30)*2*(\col+mod(\row,2)/2)},{(1+sin(30))*\row}) 
                    +(30:1) 
                    \foreach \angle in {90,150,...,360} {
                        -- +(\angle:1)
                    } -- cycle;
            }
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
% Text or other content goes here
Here is your text or other content that should appear before the hexagons.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But wait! How did I come up with `({cos(30)*2*(\col+mod(\row,2)/2)},{(1+sin(30))*\row})`? Let's analyse this:

- First the *x* part of the coodinate, which is `cos(30)*2*(\col+mod(\row,2)/2)`

Since I decided to leave the scaling to the *tikzpicture*, I chose as radius for the circumcircle of the hexagon simply 1 (in centimeters), so that the distance of every corner of the hexagon from its center is 1. The width of the hexagon is therefore `cos(30)*2`, which results from trigonometry.

Now we also need to shift the hexagon by half its width in every second row which can be achieved using `mod(\row,2)/2` since `mod(\row,2)` outputs 1 for every odd and 0 for every even `\row`.

- The *y* part of the coordinate, `(1+sin(30))*\row`, can also be calculated with basic trigonometry.

---

You could even omit one `\foreach` loop and only draw the right side of the hexagon as the other sides will be drawn by the next iterations anyways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
% Here come the hexagons
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nx}{ceil(\paperwidth/2cm)+1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ny}{ceil(\paperheight/((1+sin(30))*1cm))+1}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south west)}]
        \foreach \row in {0,...,\ny} {
            \foreach \col in {0,...,\nx} {
                \draw[black!20] 
                    ({cos(30)*2*(\col+mod(\row,2)/2)},{(1+sin(30))*\row}) 
                    +(90:1) -- +(30:1) -- +(-30:1) -- +(-90:1);
            }
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
% Text or other content goes here
Here is your text or other content that should appear before the hexagons.

\end{document}
```

Same output as above (maybe a tad cleaner even).

---

With `scale=2` or other scaling, you'd need to adjust the formulae for `\nx` and `\ny`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
% Here come the hexagons
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, scale=2] 
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nx}{ceil(\paperwidth/2cm)/2+1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ny}{ceil(\paperheight/((1+sin(30))*1cm))/2+1}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south west)}]
        \foreach \row in {0,...,\ny} {
            \foreach \col in {0,...,\nx} {
                \draw[black!20] 
                    ({cos(30)*2*(\col+mod(\row,2)/2)},{(1+sin(30))*\row}) 
                    +(90:1) -- +(30:1) -- +(-30:1) -- +(-90:1);
            }
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
% Text or other content goes here
Here is your text or other content that should appear before the hexagons.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! But it puts the pattern on top of the text. Is it possible to have it underneath?

Comment: @lukascbossert Just put the `tikzpicture` first. It is positioned absolutely due to `remember picture`, so it doesn't matter where you put it in the code, as long as it appears somewhere on the page. Note that you need to compile at least twice, which you always need to do with `remember picture`.

Comment: @lukascbossert The pattern always goes from the lower left corner to the top. But since the whole page is covered this should not matter.

Comment: It works, but I had to put a `-1` instead of `+1` at the in ` \pgfmathsetmacro{\ny}{ceil(\paperheight/((1+sin(30))*1cm))-1}`. Great! Thanks!

Comment: @lukascbossert You need to compile at least two times, because after the first compilation the picture might not sit at the right position. Did you do that? I doubt that you need to change the defintion of `\ny` like that.

Comment: how can I adjust the size of the hexagon? e.g. to have them bigger but less on the page.

Comment: @lukascbossert You can add something like `scale=2` as option to the `tikzpicture` environment (similar like what you had originally). But then you also need to change the formulae for `\nx` and `\ny` accordingly. If you scale the hexagon with factor 2, you only need half the number.